# Why my calls to firebase/firestore are slower on my Android Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore

### The context

I've developed a Flutter app that runs on both Android and iOS devices. The app loads a list of documents from a collection stored in Firestore.

### The problem

I've observed significantly longer loading times on Android devices. I've conducted numerous tests using simulators, emulators, and real devices across various Android and iOS versions. While the tests consistently yielded fast results on iOS, the performance on Android real devices was considerably poorer. The performance further deteriorates when adding some `orderBy` on the request.

### Test result sample (with real devices)

| OS | Fields | Documents | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IOS | 10 | 2750 | 0.5sec |
| ANDROID | 10 | 2750 | 2.8sec |
| IOS | 10 | 4795 | 0.7sec |
| ANDROID | 10 | 4795 | 3.5sec |

### How to reproduce and test ?

1. Download the code from my [Github](https://github.com/NicolasJacquet/android_perf).
2. Retrieve the necessary packages.
3. Run the app on a real device (results may not be consistent on emulators).

Within the running app, there are several buttons that allow you to test the calls. You can view the results either directly in the app or within the logs.

---

Please find the main.dart code here :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = const Settings(
    persistenceEnabled: false,
    cacheSizeBytes: Settings.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Android perf test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blueAccent),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Android perf test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String elapsedTime = '0';
  String itemLength = '0';
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Call took : $elapsedTime sec',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                Text('For $itemLength documents', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Test load with 10 fields'),
                  onPressed: () => testThis('products10'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Test load with 50 fields'),
                  onPressed: () => testThis('products50'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Test load with 10 fields and orderBy'),
                  onPressed: () => testThis('products10', withOrder: true),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Test load with 50 fields and orderBy'),
                  onPressed: () => testThis('products50', withOrder: true),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            if (loading)
              Container(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> testThis(String collectionName, {bool withOrder = false}) async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    print('Test start with $collectionName');
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();

    if (withOrder) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collectionName)
          .orderBy('ein', descending: true)
          .orderBy('name')
          .orderBy('language')
          .orderBy('company')
          .get()
          .then(
            (value) => setLength(value.docs.length),
          );
    } else {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).get().then(
            (value) => setLength(value.docs.length),
          );
    }

    stopwatch.stop();
    setState(() {
      elapsedTime = stopwatch.elapsed.toString();
    });
    print('Call took : ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  }

  void setLength(int length) {
    setState(() {
      itemLength = length.toString();
    });
    print('Documents loaded : $length');
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please, do not post your code from GitHub and please, never share your private keys, you're exposed to bad actors that can use your keys with bad intentions. I recommend you to remove that info ASAP.

Comment: Hi @MarianoZorrilla, how do you advice to share the code so that people can help and see the problem ? I didn't want to share only a small part of code, but my goal was to share the maximum info so it's easily testable.

Comment: @Nico use environment variables to hold & read the private API keys. You can set them on your system/environment or store in a .env file that you don't commit to github. https://www.sandromaglione.com/techblog/how-to-use-environmental-variables-in-flutter

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla If you are referring to the values in `firebase_options.dart`, those are configuration data that has to be in the client and not server-side API keys. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: While the description of the issue is pretty clear, SO is not a project level troubleshooting service. We can assist with specific coding issues only. The rule of thumb is to include a minimal example that replicates the issue. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The issue described sounds pretty straightforward, so include the minimum code you use to read Firestore and sample data and we'll take a look!

Comment: Well, I though It was pretty clear and all code available, but I added the main.dart code, which in my opinion will not really help but at least people will have some code

Comment: Thank you. Just a FYI, if you were to close your project then the linked code would not be accessible to future readers, therefore the question would be useless. The idea here is to share knowledge and code so not only can you get your issue resolved, but also future readers that may have the same or similar issue. To be clear, the code in the question is running on Android and takes 3.5 to complete, and the *exact same code* 100% identical runs on iOS and takes .5 to complete?

Comment: Yes, I see your point, it's totally true ! Thanks for your feedback ! 
And yes that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Flutter version in your pubspec.lock on GitHub. One possible reason could be that iOS is using the new impeller engine. Currently, Android might not be able to support impeller stably.

Try this piece of code, disable the impeller engine,

```
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

and see if it affects the performance on iOS